# Magento 2 : Layered Filter Navigation Overwrite

Tags: magento2, overrides, layered-navigation

I overwrite Layered Filter navigation, and is working in localhost but not working on server. On server its remove default(core) layered navigation filter  (No Filter block called on category view page).

I check that no other module overwrite layered filter navigation.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in here: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CrHagK9XYAAvDf1.jpg ?

Comment: Now seriously, are your sure you cleared the cache and the generation folder? Are you sure your module is loaded?